# Can the cohomology ring of the two-fold torus be calculated abstractly?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In our lectures, we are given an unusual definition of cohomology and cup products which makes explicit calculations a bit tedious (that is, even more tedious than usual).

For the $n$- and $m$-spheres $S^n$ and $S^m$, I know that there’s an isomorphism of rings
$$H^•(S^n×S^m) \overset \simeq \longrightarrow H^•(S^n) \otimes H^•(S^m).$$
Can I use merely this fact, and other basic facts about cohomology like the Mayer–Vietoris sequence, Poincaré duality and the functoriality of cohomology to actually calculate the cohomology of the [two-fold torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-2_surface)? What other  facts would I need?

Comment: What is the double torus?

Comment: If you know *only* that isomorphism and functoriality, you cnanot do much: it could be that $H^*(X)=0$ for all $X$...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I mean the two-fold torus – the compact oriented surface of genus $2$. I don’t care much about which definition is used, though. Hm, I was hoping that some relations of spheres with the two-fold torus would give some usable ring-homomorphisms. Is there a plausibilty argument why there cannot be any usable induced cohomological ring homomorphisms which would tell me something about the cohomology ring structure of the double torus?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I did misunderstand you: The cohomology of the double torus (as a graded abelian group) is known, Poincaré-Duality is known and Mayer–Vietoris is given as a tool as well as excision and the like. The only known cohomology ring structures are spheres and product of spheres, though. I edited the question – is it clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It is not clear to me what you mean by "abstractly", I take this to mean "using general principles alone", which is only slightly less ambiguous.)

In any case, I propose the following. Our double torus is the connected sum $T^2\# T^2$ (where as usual $T^2=S^1\times S^1$).

1. There is a general description of $H^\ast(M\# N)$ (with $M$ and $N$ oriented manifolds) in terms of $H^\ast(M)$ and $H^\ast(N)$, which is described in detail [for instance here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98376/cup-products-of-connected-sum). I think that this can be regarded as a basic fact about cohomology, in fact much more basic than e.g. Poincaré duality.
2. Using the description in 1, we are left with the task of calculating the cohomology ring $H^\ast(T^2)$. But as you say, Künneth's theorem gives $H^\ast(T^2)=H^\ast(S^1)\otimes H^\ast(S^1)=\bigwedge_{\mathbf{Z}}[x,y]$ with $x$ and $y$ in degree $1$. (The description of the cohomology ring of the spheres is obvious.)

It is possible, using simplicial cohomology, to describe the cohomology ring of the double torus using only the definition. This is done for instance in Hatcher's algebraic topology (page 207, Example 3.7). But I regard the approach above as more satisfactory, and I think it would be misleading to think that using the definition alone is the way to do these kinds of computations in general; *in my opinion*, if one does a generic computation with (co-)homology, one cannot do a lot using the definition alone.

Comment: Despite your negative review of my answer in the other post, I think I should still give you an upvote for your effort spent at here.

Comment: @Bombyxmori Note that it was against the answer, not against you. So please don't take it personally.

Comment: If I did, I would not upvote your post you know....

Comment: I would like to award you the bounty, but can you expand a bit on your first point, how to calculate $H^*(M\#N)$? I cannot quite follow the argument in the linked answer, can you expand on it a bit/give your own answer? Some questions: What properties should the augmentation have/how is it defined? How is $S^{d-1} → M \# N → M ∨ N$ a cofbibration and how does it give the *canonical* identifaction $R = H^*(M\#N)$?

Comment: @k.stm: it is clearly an injection with closed image. Cofibrations give isomorphisms in cohomology.

Answer (score 2):

I think Qiaochu Yuan's post (https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/the-cohomology-of-the-n-torus/) is quite relevant. In particular the first part gives a derivation of the cohomology (group) of the $n$-torus using Mayer–Vietoris . Of course you need more tools to compute the ring structure, but I think Qiaochu did a quite good job at elaborating it as well. So I feel an answer by me might be simply duplicating some parts of what he did. Of course you can use Poincare duality, but the computation of the homology groups takes some effort if you just use Mayer–Vietoris or long exact sequence.

Comment: The post is about the $n$-torus. I haven’t read it yet – how it will the blog post help with the *two-fold* torus/ *double* torus?

Comment: @k.stm: It is quite similar if you did the computations. You can view the $n$-torus as the gluing of two $n-1$ torus on two ends. And you use some induction argument to carry out Mayer-Vietoris. The higher dimensional two-fold torus case is analogous.